# String formatting: scale and precision from String.Format

Tags: c#, .net, string, format

I need to format numbers (using WPF converters), and the only way I can do it is via string.Format.

I have two formatting parameters: *scale and precision.*
I can achieve what I need separately, but it doesn't work with both:

**Example (that works):**

```
string.Format("{0:#,##0,,}", 1234567890.123m) == "1,235"
string.Format("{0:#,#.000}", 1234567890.123m) == "1,234,567,890.123"
```

**What I need:**

```
string.Format("????", 1234567890.123m) == "1,234.568"
```

(which would mean 1,234.568 Millions)
As you can see I can't find a format pattern that would both scale and also display decimals.

Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A colleague of mine got the solution:

```
string.Format("{0:#,##0,,.000}", 1234567890.123m) == "1,234.568"
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't think the string format will do this for you. You will have to divide it on your own.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks! I'll wait a bit if by any chance someone else got an answer, and I'll accept your answer.